# How to use GPS coordinates from a text file in a googlemaps page?

Tags: php, html, google-maps-api-3

I am copying GPS coordinates into a text file to use for a website displaying a google map. Before, I was using a php script to take the gps coordinates and some long strings to create a kml document that I could display. That doesn't seem like the best way. I have the text file, gpsinfo.txt, with information for 4 datapoints that looks like this when opened:

```
7.784606,63.10403 7.784606,64.10403 7.784606,65.10403 7.784606,66.10403
```

How should I use that text file to create the 4 points on my webpage?

I was thinking about using a php file to create a js file that my webpage could read, but that doesn't sound like a very clean method.

Comment: Why not just store the coordinates in a javascript friendly format? Or if there are that few, just keep them in the PHP file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am doing to solve this:

I have a php file scrape some webpages to get GPS coordinates, and then I copy them into a text file but in a JSON format:

```
  [{ "boat": "Edda", "coordinates" : { "lat" : 7.80086, "lon": 64.75658}}, { "......
```

Then I have a php file that is reads the file and is accessed by my webpage using ajax and outputs the string and then the webpage handles it.

ajax on webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var point;
microAjax("BackgroundFiles/genjsonGPS.php", function (res) {

  var json_obj = JSON.parse(res.toString());

  initialize(json_obj);
  window.setTimeout(function(){

    }, 500);      
});

  </script>
```

genjsonGPS.php:

```
<?php

$myFile = "vesselGPS.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$vesselGPS = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);

echo($vesselGPS);


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to read the same textfile using php and then construct what you need.

Example:

```
<?php

$contents = file_get_contents("gpsinfo.txt");
$contentsArray = explode(" ", $contents);

$gpsCoords = array(); // your final result to use when constructing javascript for maps

foreach($contentsArray as $key => $gpsItem)
{
    $gpsArray = explode("," $gpsItem);
    $gpsArray[$key]['lat'] = $gpsItem[0];  
    $gpsArray[$key]['lon'] = $gpsItem[1];
    // The latter two might change as I am not sure which is 
    // the lon and which is the lat at your end
}

?>
```

The code can be used in a function returning the array of coordinates or just simply inline, depending on your code style.

Another way of doing it is to store the coordinates into a JSON array and then try to fetch it and feed it directly into javascript. Though in my example you would just need to store the data in some specific way: i.e. call in php to construct an array or call a function in javascript for each coordinate which would place the marker on the map.
PHP runs way before javascript (serverside, whereas js runs client side), which means there are multiple ways of approaching a solution.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I think this is a good way. I have been working on another problem at the moment but when I get a chance to implement this ill accept the answer

Comment: No probs, please do tell how you solved it, even if you use another method.